# Write exponential function in R

Tags: r

I am implementing the kinetic model proposed by [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519398907871) (modelling diffusion of molecules into different compartments of a biological cell) in R. However; I am not sure if the following code is correct (the main struggle is the exp() function)

```
A2_t_1_calc <- function(t, C0plus, C0minus, Eplus, Eminus, A1_0, D21, D32, G12, G23, V3, P42) {
    y = C0plus * (V3 * Eplus + D32 * G23)*exp(Eplus * t) + C0minus * (V3 * Eminus + D32 * G23)*exp(Eminus * t) + ((D21 * A1_0)/(D21 * G12 + P42))
}
```

For this formula:
[image: formula from the linked paper]

As written, I am unsure if I "translated" the exp function correctly. Therefore, I appreciate the correction and help!

Comment: what is the exact struggle you are having with `exp()`?

Comment: I am not sure, whether I use the exp() correctly. As an example, can the first line of the image be written as: `C0plus * (V3 * Eplus + D32 * G23)*exp(Eplus * t)`  ? Is it really "just" multiplying by exp()? (my background in math and coding is not strong)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you! I also found some missing terms in the calculations. Now the equations are correct.